# How to set font in PIL?

Tags: fonts, python-imaging-library

How to set the same font like the LaTeX uses? I tried the following code. I used a similar way I use for matplotlib.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r"\usepackage{bm}", r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]

params = {'text.usetex' : True,
          'font.size' : 25,
          'font.family' : 'lmodern',
          'text.latex.unicode': True,
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params)

im = Image.new("RGB", (512, 512), (128, 128, 128))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

draw.multiline_text((100, 1000), 'Pillow sample', fill=(0, 0, 0), font=params)

im.show()
```

I got the following error:

```
    draw.multiline_text((100, 1000), 'Pillow sample', fill=(0, 0, 0), font=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 234, in multiline_text
    line_spacing = self.textsize('A', font=font)[1] + spacing
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 263, in textsize
    return font.getsize(text, direction, features)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'getsize'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `params` you use as argument for argument `font` in `multiline_text` is a dictionary, while that function expects a font object. So you first need to create a font object from those parameters. See [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html).

```
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf", 40)
```